# Why does my Linkedin share button not work?

Tags: user-interface, share, linkedin-api

I want to create a share button for Linkedin, the GUI button is all set up, but it doesn't work when clicking it. I researched a bit and came to the conclusion that using the same sharing mechanism, other sites work but mine doesn't.

I narrowed the problem down and now I'm trying to figure out why google.com works but my site doesn't. I don't use my real company website because it's personal information, but it's a website that has been on the internet for more than 10 years (in case this information is useful). When I go to the links, my website throws an error, but Google works fine.

Ⓧ　https://www.linkedin.com/cws/share/?url=https://www.my-company-website.com

〇　https://www.linkedin.com/cws/share/?url=https://www.google.com

Is there any pre-requisite I'm missing, which makes my site not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized my server was blocking Linkedin (to reduce traffic from Linkedin bots). That's why it wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

As hint: I was working on closed webpage (for outside users) and that also causing problems with Linkedin share button.

Hint 2: Website uses Lets Encrypt! SSL and information mentioned here is a fake news https://wordpress.org/support/topic/linkedin-share-button-not-working-3/ Work's fine!

Answer (score 0):

If you ever get stuck on trying to figure out *why* your page simply doesn't populate nice preview data on your LinkedIn share page, then check out the [**LinkedIn Post Inspector**](https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/).

Insert the URL of your page (i.e., example.com), not the URL you are using to share (i.e., linkedin.com/share?url=example.com).  You'll get detailed information on how your site will appear and why, like, for instance, sharing wikipedia.org...

[image]

*Hope this helps someone else with a LinkedIn share issue!*